# Linq, join, group, count > select more values

Tags: c#, linq

With LINQ i'm doing the following to select my suppliers and their product count:

```
from s in context.Suppliers 
join p in context.Products on s equals p.Supplier 
group s by s.CompanyName 
into result 
select new {   
    SupplierName = result.Key,   
    ProductCount = result.Count() 
}
```

this works just fine, but i want to select some more properties from my supplier table, SupplierId and SupplierAddress, like:

```
....    
select new {   
    SupplierName = result.Key,   
    ProductCount = result.Count(),   
    SupplierId = ..,   
    SupplierAddress = ..,  
    }
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You are on the right track, just verify two things... Does your output class have a field to store SupplierId and SupplierAddress? You are only pasting part of the code, can we get the entire line, including the LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're sure all `Supplier` groups with the same `CompanyName` are guranteed to have the same `Id` and `Address`?

```
from s in context.Suppliers 
join p in context.Products on s equals p.Supplier 
group s by s.CompanyName 
into result 
select new {   
    SupplierName = result.Key,   
    ProductCount = result.Count(),
    SupplierId = result.First().Id,
    SuppliedAddress = result.First().Address 
}
```

It would look more natural if you grouped by `Id` instead, or maybe all of them:

```
from s in context.Suppliers 
join p in context.Products on s equals p.Supplier 
group s by new { s.CompanyName, s.Id, s.Address } 
into result 
select new {   
    ProductCount = result.Count(),
    SupplierName = result.Key.CompanyName,   
    SupplierId = result.Key.Id,
    SuppliedAddress = result.Key.Address 
}
```

Comment: Implicit in `result.FirstOrDefault().Id` and `result.FirstOrDefault().Address` is the possibility of a null exception.

Comment: I concur with splender. If you are going to use the value without checking for `null`, there's no point in using the `OrDefault` versions.

Comment: @svick: You're absolutely right, for some reason I imagined there is no `First()` method in LINQ. This is getting really late here and I think I need to get some sleep..

Comment: Yes, you're completely right that it's better to group by Id, but i just typed this as a quick example to make my question clear.

Comment: The second example suits perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

Um... Unless I'm mistaken, this can be done considerably more cleanly:

```
context
    .Products
    .GroupBy(p=>p.Supplier)
    .Select(result=>new {
        SupplierName = result.Key,   
        ProductCount = result.Count(),
        SupplierId = result.Key.Id,   
        SupplierAddress = result.Key.Address,  
    }
```

The joins come out of the box from the FK relationships in the DB, so a `Product` already has a `Supplier`. It seems you spotted this setup in your own code ( `...equals p.Supplier` ), then failed to understand its meaning. Apologies for changing from comprehension syntax to method chains. They come more naturally to me.

Supplemental to @Dan's comment (which is likely correct for Linq2Objects), in Linq2Sql (I can't vouch for L2E, but I imagine it's much the same), if you group by a property that is generated by a FK relationship, the resulting generated SQL will GROUP BY the key value, not the entire entity.

Comment: Note that you'll also need `Supplier` to implement `IEquatable` for this to work.

Comment: @Dan, I extended my answer to address your comment.